# Wordpress auto scaled instanced under ELB giving 503 error

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I need to link example.com to two AWS Wordpress instances. example.com has an A-record pointing the ELB URL. 
As mentioned [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL), I added

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

and in theme's functions.php

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Also added `define('RELOCATE',true);` in wp-config.php.
Before adding these, Wordpress works by hitting the public IPs, but after adding these, I simply receive 503 error from example.com, and if I try the public IPs, they're simply redirected to example.com, thus giving 503 again.

Another thing to note is that if I replace example.com with the respective EC2 IPs in the above configuration files, the site works, but relative URLs have a bad format like `www.example.com/<ip-address>/contact-us#`

I am probably following a wrong approach to deal with Auto-scaling and ELB.